# Is there a faster way to read data from s3 in pyspark/python

Tags: python, performance, amazon-s3, pyspark, databricks

my data is partitioned in s3 as mnt/.../year=xxx/month=mm/day=dd. when i try read data corresponding to a month using .read() in pyspark it takes a lot of time. is there a better way to read data than just doing a .read().The file format is avro.

Comment: This is too broad. What does _it takes a long time_ mean, exactly? Have you done any benchmarking/profiling? We need more information in general.